# Example for mocking apache HTTPS request using Betamax version 2.x in java?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, betamax

I am trying to mock Apache HTTPS calls in Java, using Betamax 2.x.

The old documentation is deprecated, and the docs for 2.x are still in progress.

Can someone help with an example of how this can be done?